# How to integrate social logins with existing user schema in my app (SPA + Custom API) using Auth0?

Tags: auth0, auth0-connection

I have an app that uses the “Username-Password-Authentication” database connection (username and password to login), its successfully integrated with custom DB, i want to change the app so users can just register + login without ever needing to add a password or username, i want to remove the old method and use a social login (google) for this.

Here is my current solution (this app is only for learning purposes, i don’t need to actually migrate users from old to new login method):

Since flows in social logins are limited, i am only able to use the “Post Login” flow:

- register social user to local db
- if success → accept login
- if user already exists → accept login
- if fail (server errors) → reject login

Whats usually the general approach here? is my current solution ok?

I originally tried to asked this question [here](https://community.auth0.com/t/how-to-integrate-social-logins-with-existing-user-schema/126192) but moved to stackoverlfow since that website is currently very laggy and unusable for me